# Import MySQL tables into Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have recently created a PHP application which connects to my MySQL database and displays the table information. Where Django is concerned, I am only familiar with them being created in SQLite by creating the relevant models.

Is there a way to do this in reverse? So have Django create models from the tables in MySQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use your existing schema to create tables. The official documentation is at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/legacy-databases/

There are two commands:

```
python manage.py inspectdb
```

This will give you the output of running:

```
python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```

Django won't know how you want to break these models up into separate application modules, so you'll need to do that on your own, if necessary.

Comment: Perfect thanks, so I guess I can just pick the relevant classes from that output if I didn't want them all in models.py?

Comment: Yes, just use what you need for your Django app. The code that function creates can be a little messy since it's so generic.